# Check if a gobject was correctly freed

Tags: unit-testing, glib, gobject

I'm using glib's Testing framework for unit testing. My library also uses gobject, in my test unities I want to check if after the last _unref of each object the object was correctly freed. When g_test_trap_fork was available I used it after each _unref, calling _unref for a second time and then checking for g_test_trap_assert_failed ().

However, now that g_test_trap_fork is becoming deprecated I'm moving towards g_test_trap_subprocess. The problem is that now I would have to write a separated test case for each _unref to be checked and since each case could contain several objects that would imply on the repetition of every test case adding a second _unref for each one already present.

For example, I tried to fix like this:

```
NcmVector *v = test->v;
GVariant *var = ncm_vector_get_variant (v);

g_assert (!g_variant_is_floating (var));
g_assert (g_variant_is_container (var));
g_assert_cmpuint (ncm_vector_len (v), ==, g_variant_n_children (var));

{
  NcmVector *nv = ncm_vector_new_variant (var);
  gint i;

  g_assert_cmpuint (ncm_vector_len (v), ==, ncm_vector_len (nv));
  for (i = 0; i < ncm_vector_len (v); i++)
  {
    ncm_assert_cmpdouble (ncm_vector_get (v, i), ==, ncm_vector_get (nv, i));
  }

  ncm_vector_free (nv);
  NCM_TEST_FAIL (ncm_vector_free (nv));
}

g_variant_unref (var);
NCM_TEST_FAIL (g_variant_unref (var); fprintf (stderr, "fail (%s)", g_variant_get_type_string (var)));
```

Where the macro NCM_TEST_FAIL is given by:

```
#define NCM_TEST_FAIL(cmd) \
G_STMT_START { \
  if (g_test_subprocess ()) \
  { \
    cmd; \
    exit (0); \
  } \
  else \
  { \
    g_test_trap_subprocess (NULL, 0, 0); \
    g_test_trap_assert_failed (); \
  } \
} G_STMT_END
```

The problem with this solution is that it can be only used once in each test case. If used for a second time, as in the example above, it would only test the first appearance of g_test_subprocess ().

I thought about checking inside of the gobject structure for the reference count just before the last _unref to check if it is == 1. But that would involve accessing a private part of that structure which I would avoid if possible.

Any ideas of how to check for erroneous code several times inside the same test case?

Comment: A GVariant is not a GObject.

Comment: @nemequ yes I know, it's not a *GObject*, that's other reason to find a general way to check if reference counted "objects" are freed correctly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you need to check for a `GObject` to be disposed correctly, you can use `g_object_add_weak_pointer()`, for instance:

```
FooObject *o = g_object_new (foo_object_get_type (), NULL);

g_assert_nonnull (o);

// the contents of the pointer are reset to NULL when the last reference to
// the GObject instance goes away; by passing a pointer to the same instance
// we can check it for NULL later
g_object_add_weak_pointer (G_OBJECT (o), (gpointer *) &o);

// ...test FooObject...

// drop the last reference
g_object_unref (o);

// at this point, the object should be NULL if nothing is holding
// an additional reference.
g_assert_null (o);
```

in the example above, though, you're using `GVariant`, which is not a `GObject`, and thus it does not have weak references.

GLib does not have a common reference counted type for binary compatibility reasons; all the common code for a reference counted type is in `GObject`.

Comment: Any ideas of how to solve this problem for GArrays, GHashTables, GVariants, etc, etc?

Comment: you can't: they may be refcounted types (as of recently, for GArray and GHashTable), but they don't have weak references so you cannot know if the last reference has been dropped.

Comment: Alternatively to `g_assert_nonnull`, which may terminate the program, one can use `g_print("%p\n", o)`. Comparing with `NULL` may segfault.

Comment: If test fails, then `g_object_remove_weak_pointer()` is needed to avoid stack corruption when object is freed.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the number of instance of a type with [g_type_instance_count](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Type-Information.html#g-type-get-instance-count) (`export GOBJECT_DEBUG=instance-count`)

```
MyObject *obj = g_object_new (my_object_get_type (), NULL);

g_type_get_instance_count(my_object_get_type ());// return 1
g_object_unref(obj);
g_type_get_instance_count(my_object_get_type ());// return 0
```

but you can check memory leak with Valgrind.